# Angular momentum in non inertial frame

Tags: orbital-mechanics, astronomy, astrodynamics

How to express the angular momentum in non inertial Earth frame like Earth Fixed frame so that angular momentum is conserved ?

Is H = R x mV still valid when R and V are taken in the rotating frame ?

Comment: Welcome on the Space SE! Your question is not really about the space exploration, I suggest to try https://physics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: This question is better suited to [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), and [off topic](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: It's a good question for sure. Before you ask there, I'd recommend you look there for existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\vec H = \vec r \times (m \vec v)$ is still valid in a rotating frame. That's the definition, after all. Whether this definition has any meaning is a different question. Angular momentum is not necessarily conserved in a rotating frame. Consider, for example, a spacecraft in a geosynchronous orbit that has a non-zero inclination with respect to the equator and a non-zero eccentricity. The angular velocity vector as defined by $\vec r \times (m \vec v)$ points all over the place.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to squeeze this in just before closure, having a good answer *here* is a net benefit to the site. I'm not sure this should have been closed.